# Null Reference exception when post value back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am posting value back from Html.BeginForm's dropdown as follows:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Transport", FormMethod.Post))
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.Projects, New SelectList(Model.Projects, "Id", "Nazwa"), "Select project", New With {.class = "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"})
    @<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
End Using
```

Then value is going to my controller:

```
 <HttpPost()> _
   <ActionName("Index")> _
    Public Function IndexPost(fc As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
            If IsNumeric(fc(0)) Then
                Dim ass As Integer = fc(0)    'Id projektu
            End If
        End If
        Return View()
    End Function
```

then when it comes to Return View() i am receiving error on `@Html.DropDownListFor` line as below:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_ypztrmjr.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Answer (score 0):

If ModelState is false, you are returning to the view and in the view, and the `Html.DrpoDownListFor` method is going to use `Projects` collection of the viewmodel/model passed to the view.

**Remember HTTP is stateless.** you need to reload the data to render your dropdown again before returning to the view. also,you need to pass the same viewmodel/model object to the view also (Same as you did in your GET action)

Also it is a good idea to use your viewmodel instance in your GET and POST action methods to transfer data between your view and action method

So Let's assume we have a viewmodel like this

```
Public Class CreateUser
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property SelectedProject() As String
        Get
            Return m_SelectedProject
        End Get
        Set
            m_SelectedProject = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_SelectedProject As String
    Public Property Projects() As List(Of SelectListItem)
        Get
            Return m_Projects
        End Get
        Set
            m_Projects = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Projects As List(Of SelectListItem)
End Class
```

And in your GET action, you will create an object of this, set the `Projects` collection and send to the view and in your HttpPost action method, you will get an instance of the same viewmodel when user submits the form. When `ModelState.IsValid` is false, We will reload the `Projects` collection and send the view model again to the view.

```
Public Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim vm = New CreateUser()
    ' Hard coded for demo. You may replace it with data from db
    vm.Projects = New List(Of SelectListItem)() From { _
        New SelectListItem() With { _
            Key .Value = "MI", _
            Key .Text = "MI" _
        }, _
        New SelectListItem() With { _
            Key .Value = "OH", _
            Key .Text = "Ohio" _
        } _
    }
    Return View()
End Function

<HttpPost> _
Public Function Index(model As CreateUser) As ActionResult

    If ModelState.IsValid Then
          ' Save

    End If
    ' Reload the Projects collection
    ' Hard coded for demo. You may replace it with data from db
    model.Projects = New List(Of SelectListItem)() From { _
        New SelectListItem() With { _
            Key .Value = "MI", _
            Key .Text = "MI" _
        }, _
        New SelectListItem() With { _
            Key .Value = "OH", _
            Key .Text = "OHio" _
        } _
    }
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

Assuming your view is strongly typed to the CreateUser viewmodel. Here is the c# version of it. Please convert to VB.NET

```
@model CreateUser
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedProject, Model.Projects,"select one")
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to reload the data for Model.Projects.  My guess is that on your initial Get Action of the View, you set the Model.Projects to a collection of projects.  You have not set it in your post so when it returns the model is empty.  It cannot render a null collection.  Another option is to use Ajax if you don't want to reload the project list.